# Download Image from url to the device

Tags: android, url, download, imageview

i'm trying to download image from url
then load it

here is my code, and i have no idea why its not working

Downloading Code :

```
                    URL url = new URL("http://myurl.com/" + ItemName + ".png");

                    URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();

                    conection.connect();

                    InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                    File fileUri = new File (CategoryActivity.Application.getCacheDir(), ItemName + ".png");
                    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileUri);

                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                    while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                        output.write(data, 0, count);
                    }

                    output.flush();
                    output.close();
                    input.close();

                    Log.e("","Done Downloading");
```

Reading Code :

```
  File imgFile = new File (CategoryActivity.Application.getCacheDir(), ItemName + ".png");


        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: you have an error or nothing in result?

Comment: no errors
just empty imageView